# Imageview and textView in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my android app, I have a set of images.. I make use of ViewPager to show the images and the corresponding text.. All the images are 300 * 300 pixels in size.. My problem is in xhdpi devices, the images are shown very small.. whereas in hdpi device it is quite ok. I tried setting `"android:adjustViewBounds="true"` but of no use.

EDIT: My images are in drawable-nodpi folder.

Here is the code that I use,

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) container.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);

ImageView customepager_iv = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custompager_iv);
customepager_iv.setImageBitmap(icon); //setting some icon

TextView custompager_tv = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.custompager_tv);
custompager_tv.setText(categoryDB.get(position));

((ViewPager) container).addView(layout, 0);
```

and the layout is that I'm trying to set inside the Viewpager is this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custompager_rl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custompager_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/custompager_iv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Subject"
        android:textColor="#e4533e"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custompager_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/someImage" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any pointers on how to resolve this?

Comment: try  android:scaleType="fitXY" in your ImageVIew

Comment: @Brontok even after changing to android:scaleType="fitXY" in Imageview, the images are very small in xhdpi devices.

Comment: Where are you storing your images? If you're using drawable resources, you should store them in res/drawable-*dpi subfolders, because then system will scale them according to screen density. The best is probably res/drawable-mdpi.

Comment: Thanks @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem. After moving all the images into drawable folder it worked fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the screen density at run time (LDPI,HDPI,MDPI or XHDPI) using

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int densityDpi = (int)(metrics.density * 160f);
```

and then change the height and width of your ImageView accordingly at run time say 400*400 for XHDPI

Update your layout like this

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/custompager_iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/someImage" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As per @ÁronNemmondommegavezetéknevem 's comment, I have moved all my images in drawable folder and the images are displaying correctly in all the devices..

Posting this here for the benefit of others.. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I've posted it as a solution, for benefit of others:

If you're using drawable resources as images, you should store them in res/drawable-*dpi subfolders, because then system will scale them according to screen density. The best place to store them is res/drawable-mdpi, because then 1px in an image will take 1dp on screen.